# How to remove blanks from drop down in Excel Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, pivot-table

I'm trying to create a pivot table that represents a parent-child assembly list. It works nearly perfectly except for one issue. Anywhere there is a blank, a full row with the very little info it has gets inserted as a dropdown see the example red cells. I want to remove this drop down so that only the true qty is shown without the clutter. Suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since the (blank) in column G have a parent-child relationship, you may not be able to hide them well using the Filter function.
You ccould try to use conditional formatting to display them in other ways.

1. Press Ctrl+A to select all Pivot table, click C*onditional
   Formatting>New Rule>Format only cells that contain*.
2. Set that rule type to Cell Value/equal to/(blank).
3. Click Format.
4. On the Number tab, select Custom, then type three semi-colons ";;;".
5. Continue clicking OK until you return to the worksheet.

[image]